# gcloud container clusters upgrade --node-pool: it timed out; how do i use gcloud to tell when it's done?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to upgrade my gke cluster from this command:

```
gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME --cluster-version=1.15.11-gke.3 \
   --node-pool=default-pool --zone=ZONE
```

I get the following output:

```
Upgrading test-upgrade-172615287... Done with 0 out of 5 nodes (0.0%): 2 being processed...done.
Timed out waiting for operation <Operation
 clusterConditions: []
 detail: u'Done with 0 out of 5 nodes (0.0%): 2 being processed'
 name: u'operation-NUM-TAG'
 nodepoolConditions: []
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(UPGRADE_NODES, 4)
 progress: <OperationProgress
 metrics: [<Metric
 intValue: 5
 name: u'NODES_TOTAL'>, <Metric
 intValue: 0
 name: u'NODES_FAILED'>, <Metric
 intValue: 0
 name: u'NODES_COMPLETE'>, <Metric
 intValue: 0
 name: u'NODES_DONE'>]
 stages: []>
 …
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(RUNNING, 2)
 …>
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.upgrade) Operation [DATA_SAME_AS_IN_TIMEOUT] is still running
```

I just discovered `gcloud config set builds/timeout 3600` so I hope this doesn't happen again, like in my CI. But if it does, is there a gcloud command that lets me know that the upgrade is still in progress?  These two didn't provide that:

```
gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME --zone=ZONE
gcloud container node-pools describe default-pool --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME --zone=ZONE
```

**Note:** Doing this upgrade in the console took **2 hours** so I'm not surprised the command-line attempt timed out. This is for a CI, so I'm fine looping and sleeping for 4 hours or so before giving up. But what's the command that will let me know when the cluster is being upgraded, and when it either finishes or fails?  The UI is showing the cluster is still undergoing the upgrade, so I assume there is some command.

TIA as usual

Comment: Does this happen with all clusters? If you create a new cluster and upgrade it does it still take 2 hours?
You may want to consider opening up an Issue Tracker with google so they can help you troubleshoot this if there's something broken internally.
https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Thanks for the issues link.

Comment: If you run `gcloud container operations list` do you see the running operation?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed (and yes, the op is marked DONE now).

Answer (score 3):

Bumped into the same issue.

All `gcloud` commands, including `gcloud container operations wait OPERATION_ID`(https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/operations/wait), have the same 1-hour timeout.

At this point, there is no other way to wait for the upgrade to complete than to query `gcloud container operations list` and check the STATUS in a loop.